# 3ds max Autogrid is not working

Tags: 3ds-max

I am trying to create one box, keeping AUTOGRID on. But The box is slanted, not parallel with the surface.

I dnt understand what mistakes am making. Please help.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Grid and Snap Toggle settings (Right Click)
User Grid tab
Change from *World space* to **Object Space**